# Cannot set a java annotation member called type in scala?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am trying to port some java code to scala.  The code uses annotations with a member called `type` however this is a keyword in scala. Is there a way to address this valid java member in scala?

Here is the Java code

```
@Component(
        name = "RestProcessorImpl",
        type = mediation // Compile error
        )
public class RestProcessorImpl {
 // impl
}
```

This part of the code is identical in scala except that `type` is a keyword so it does not compile.  Is there a way to escape the `type` keyword?

This is also a problem with java classes with a `type` member

**HasType.java**

```
package spike1;

public class HasType {
    public String type() { 
        return "the type";
    }
}
```

**UseType.scala**

```
class UseType {
    def hasType = new HasType
    hasType.type() // Compile error
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use backticks to get around illegal identifiers:

```
val type = 1    // error
val `type` = 1  // fine
```

So with your code, you can do this:

```
val hasType = new HasType
hasType.`type`()   // no error
```

Comment: Excellent, I know that there must have been a way, that is just what I was looking for.